# Suggest Merge - 3 x WCF settings tags into WCF configuration

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

The following 3 tags are WCF configuration settings (either in .config or are settable programmatically) and IMO aren't likely to warrant a full tag as the post count indicates.

[maxreceivedmessagesize](/questions/tagged/maxreceivedmessagesize) x19

[readerquotas](/questions/tagged/readerquotas) x10

[maxstringcontentlength](/questions/tagged/maxstringcontentlength) x11

Can we consider merging these tags back into [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) or [wcf-configuration](/questions/tagged/wcf-configuration) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, I don't think they should be tags to begin with. The questions with those tags seem to be just as well off without them. The [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) or [wcf-configuration](/questions/tagged/wcf-configuration) tags seem sufficient and the body of the question can then refer to the particular configuration setting.

So rather than merging these tags, I would suggest removing them from the questions. That should be easy enough to do manually (taking care of any other required edits in the process), after which they would disappear automatically.

If there is some consensus on this, I'd happily start off the process.